# How can I render a child layout inside a parent one?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a base application layout:

```
#layouts/base.html.eex
<body>
  <div id="base_layout.html">
  <!-- some content -->
    <%= render(@view_module, @view_template, assigns) %>
  <!-- some content -->
  </div>
</body>
```

And I have 20 other different layouts. I want to inherit all of them off `base.html.eex`. How can I do that? I've tried this:

```
#layouts/child_layout5.html.eex
<div id="child_layout5.html">
  <!-- some content -->
  <%= render(@view_module, @view_template, Map.put(assigns, :layout, {MyApp.LayoutView, "base.html"})) %>
</div>
```

but this just renders the base layout wrapped into `<div id="child_layout5.html">`.

Whereas I want it to be vise versa: render the content of `child_layoutXX.html.eex` inside the `base.html`, from `child_layoutXX.html.eex`

Note that `base.html` doesn't know of its children `child_layoutXX.html.eex`, how many there're, if any, what their names are, that is, `base.html` can't explicitly render any of its children by its name.

The function https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render/3 hasn't helped me thus far yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way where you pass the child layout to use in the assigns map of `render` and let the `base` layout handle using it. You can pass a different value for `child_layout` for each action. This way the `base` layout doesn't have any hardcoded child layout.

```
# controllers/page_controller.ex
defmodule MyApp.PageController do
  use MyApp.Web, :controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    conn
    |> put_layout("base.html")
    |> render("index.html", child_layout: "child_layout5.html")
  end
end
```

```
# templates/layout/base.html.eex
<body>
  <div id="base_layout.html">
    <%= render(@view_module, @view_template, Map.put(assigns, :layout, {MyApp.LayoutView, @child_layout})) %>
  </div>
</body>
```

```
# templates/layout/child_layout5.html.eex
<div id="child_layout5.html">
  <%= render(@view_module, @view_template, assigns) %>
</div>
```

```
# templates/page/index.html.eex
<!-- index.html -->
```

Output:

```
<body>
  <div id="base_layout.html">
<div id="child_layout5.html">
<!-- index.html -->
</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Edit: To make `base` template also work when `child_layout` is not passed, you can do:

```
<body>
  <div id="base_layout.html">
    <%= render(@view_module, @view_template, if(assigns[:child_layout], do: Map.put(assigns, :layout, {MyApp.LayoutView, @child_layout}), else: assigns)) %>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: ok, but how to make the parameter `@child_layout` not mandatory? that is, base.html renders a child layout it only if the parameter `@child_layout` is passed.

Comment: What do you mean by "other way"?

Comment: as you've said "Here's one way...", is there another one?

Comment: Ah. I meant that there must be other ways other people could come up with. I can't think of any better one right now. :)